# TagWith in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to use TagWith() in entity framework 6.I read a lot of posts about TagWith() in the Entity Framework Core. but none of them provide information about entity framework not core

My main need is to add few comments to generated SQL query using  EF.

```
var list = await _context.Tweets
    .TagWith("GetTweets")<<---------------------------------------comment 
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Simply because it's only supported in EF-core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EF6.TagWith) to add the functionality.

It uses a very interesting concept: it adds a where clause using constants, and then registers a [IDbCommandInterceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception#registering-interceptors) to rewrite the SQL, removing the where clause and adding the comment.

My only problem with the plugin is that in [TagWith](https://github.com/VariableNotFound/ef6-tagwith/blob/master/src/EF6.TagWith/TagWithExtensions.cs#L16), the where clause it adds defaults to being false:

```
public static IQueryable<T> TagWith<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string tag)
{
    // ...
    var tagConstant = Expression.Constant(TagMarker);
    var tagValue = Expression.Constant(tag);
    var equalsExpression = Expression.Equal(tagConstant, tagValue);
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        equalsExpression, Expression.Parameter(typeof(T))
    );
    return query.Where(predicate);
}
```

This generates the following SQL:

```
WHERE ... AND (N'!__tag!' = N'My Comment') ...
```

So if you use the IQueryable's `.ToString()` to get the SQL, it doesn't get run through the command interceptors, so you get that where clause that returns no records. It also means if anything ever goes wrong with the command interceptor, that's the SQL that would get sent to the database engine. Yikes!

In my own code, I decided to modify this to use `Expression.NotEqual`, so that the expression would be `N'!__tag!' <> N'My Comment'`, which defaults to being true.

(Actually I don't even use the `IDbCommandInterceptor`, I just leave it in the WHERE clause. Simpler code, since I only added about 8 lines for that one extension method.)